# What do I use for CONTACTS_IMPORT_CALLBACK in django-friends friends application?

Tags: django

I am trying to figure out what is needed for the CONTACTS_IMPORT_CALLBACK variable in django-friends or django-contacts-import applications (contact import is built from friends).  I have tried view models, etc..  but everything throws errors.  Neither application has documentation so I am just grasping at straws for what is needed.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember this specific setting. but knowing pinax and seeing the name, I think this is the method, that gets called after you have imported contacts from email.

To solve *this error*, you can just define a dummy method in any file and point your import call back to that, if setting this to an empty string still throws an error.

Comment: thanks, I tried adding a dummy method and it also threw an error. I could have just had a bad method or something I will take a closer look at it.